# Issue installing bower on windows

Tags: npm, bower, bower-install

I'm using Windows 7 64bit and I install Bower with

```
npm install -g bower
```

It seems to install correctly.

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/amdefine
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/amdefine
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\local\bower -> C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\local\node_
modules\bower\bin\bower
bower@1.3.3 C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\local\node_modules\bower
...
```

But bower is not working:

```
$bower
sh.exe": bower: command not found

$bower -v
sh.exe": bower: command not found
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Check if `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\local` is added to your Path Environment Variable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check if `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\local` is added to your  Path Environment Variable.

Answer (score 15):

Same problem but for me I had to add the Path Environment Variable that pointed to the AppData/Roming/ folder. I have no idea why node.js would install npm in the Roming folder. If I didn't have hidden folders turned on we never would have found it.

C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm;

Then npm works from Node.js command prompt, and bower works from GitBash.

Comment: It's explained in the troubleshooting of Node. https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#upgrading-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

Check your version of node, I was running on `v0.10.15` then updated to `v0.10.35` and that fixed the issue for me.