# How to add any path in windows Path Environment Variable

Tags: git, npm, bower, bower-install

I am using windows 8.1 and while installing bower on my machine i got an issue for which i got an answer [Issue installing bower on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23638431/issue-installing-bower-on-windows/23667165#23667165)

But i dont know how to Check if C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\local is added to your Path Environment Variable

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st Find Environment Variable:

- Control Panel -> System & Security -> System -> Advanced System Settings (Slide menu) -> Click Environment Variable Button

2nd Check if C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\loca is exist

- Go to 2nd table "system variables"
- Find "Path" variables
- Selecte and click Edit
- Search if it is here

NOTE: For more easy way copy path and paste it in a text editor. Variables Paths demarcation with ";".

Answer (score 1):

The one step method to find all Environmental Path is -

- Open cmd prompt
- Type `echo %path%`
- Press Enter

There you go you get all the `path` defined in your system. See the image, I have a `git path` setup as an Environment Variable.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the file explorer.
2. Right click on "My Computer" or "This PC" and select "Properties" option.
3. A window will open which will show Information about your Computer.
4. In this window, on the left hand side menu select the option "Advanced system settings".
5. Another window would open, in which make sure you are in "Advanced" tab and select "Environment Variables" button at the button right of the window.
6. In the "System variables" section, you will see a variable "Path", click on it and click on "Edit" button.
7. In the new pop up, click on "Add" button, enter the path you want to add and click "Ok".